# SAX find closing Tag

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, sax

Is there any feasible using the default handler class to find a corresponding XML tag? for example...

```
<Object class="my class">
  <Property>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </Property>
</Object>
<Object class="my next class">
  <Property>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </Property>
</Object>
```

I want to use the startElement() and endElement() methods but can't figure out it out at a high level. All I can think to do is use a counter, wanted to see if anyone has ever heard of an easier method. I want to split these two Object classes into 2 separate strings based on when they start and close. Any advice?

Comment: What library are you using to parse this XML?

Comment: import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to subclass the default handler class (which you need to do anyway to have any processing at all during `startElement` and `endElement`). When `startElement` is called for the `Object` tag, create an object and store a reference to it in an instance variable of your handler. When `endElement` is called, save the object somewhere and set the reference to `null`. Meanwhile, as you receive other `startElement` and `endElement` events (for the `Property` and `Value` tags), operate on the referenced object.

Repeat for the second object. At the end, you'll have saved two distinct instances of your object.

Comment: what if I had <object class="my class"><object></object></object><object class="another class"></object> would your method still work?

Comment: @EricCallan - The method as described would not work if you have nested `Object` tags. However, with a minor change--using a stack of references--the basic idea can work. When you get a `startElement` event for an object and there's already an object reference, push the existing reference onto the stack before creating a new object. On the `endElement` event, set the reference to `null` only if the stack is empty; otherwise set it to what comes off the stack when you pop it.